# Удаляется последний символ, как исправить?

Tags: javascript

```js
function pigIt(str) {
    const arrayOfWord = str.split(' ');

    return arrayOfWord.map(word => {
        const arrayOfLetter = word.split('');

        arrayOfLetter[arrayOfLetter.length-1] += arrayOfLetter[0] + 'ay';
        arrayOfLetter.splice(arrayOfLetter[0], 1);

        return arrayOfLetter.join('');
    }).join(' ');
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'));
console.log(pigIt('Hello world !'));
```

В первом случае должно вывестись: `igPay atinlay siay oolcay !`, а выводится: `igPay atinlay siay oolcay`
Во втором должно вывестись: `elloHay orldway !`, а выводится `elloHay orldway`

Comment: У вас последним элементом в `arrayOfWord` будет восклицательный знак. Он же будет единственным символом в `arrayOfLetter`. Вы к нему прибавляете `ay` и тут же удаляете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чисто в лоб в конец добавить последний элемент разделенной строки.

```js
function pigIt(str) {
    const arrayOfWord = str.split(' ');

    return arrayOfWord.map(word => {
        const arrayOfLetter = word.split('');

        arrayOfLetter[arrayOfLetter.length-1] += arrayOfLetter[0] + 'ay';
        arrayOfLetter.splice(arrayOfLetter[0], 1);

        return arrayOfLetter.join('');
    }).join(' ') + arrayOfWord[arrayOfWord.length - 1];
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool !'));
console.log(pigIt('Hello world !'));
```

Comment: Сломается, если удалить ' !' в исходной строке)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, ну так тогда пусть автор уточняет :) Там же разные знаки могут быть игнорированы.